# Tensorflow lite model inference is very slow compared to keras h5 model (VGG16 pretrained)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Tensorflow lite predictions are extremely slow compared to keras (h5) model. The behavior is similar between Colab and also on Windows 10 system. I converted the standard VGG16 model to tflite both with and without optimization (converter.optimizations = [tf.lite.Optimize.DEFAULT])

Here are the results I got:

- Keras model (540MB) prediction time: 0.14 seconds
- tflite without optimization (540MB) prediction time: 0.5 seconds
- tflite with optimization (135MB) prediction time: 39 seconds

Am I missing something here? Isn't tflite supposed to be optimized for speed? Would the behavior be different on Raspberry Pi or other 'lighter' devices?

[Link to the code on colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/13qvsrBzN2ImiLfvOzfnI4sxWTM5wgwVp?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

TensorFlow Lite isn't optimized for desktop/server, so its not surprising that it performs badly for most models in those environments. TFLite's optimized kernels (including lot of their GEMM operations) are especially geared for mobile CPUs (which don't have the same instruction set as desktop CPUs IIUC).

Standard TensorFlow is better for your use-case.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Sachin. TFLite's intended use is mobile devices.

However, if you need faster inference on a desktop or server you can try [OpenVINO](https://docs.openvino.ai/latest/openvino_docs_install_guides_overview.html). OpenVINO is optimized for Intel hardware, but it should work with any CPU. It optimizes your model by converting to Intermediate Representation (IR), performing graph pruning and fusing some operations into others while preserving accuracy. Then it uses vectorization in runtime.

It's rather straightforward to convert the Keras model to OpenVINO. The full tutorial on how to do it can be found [here](https://github.com/openvinotoolkit/openvino_notebooks/tree/main/notebooks/101-tensorflow-to-openvino). Some snippets are below.

**Install OpenVINO**

The easiest way to do it is using PIP. Alternatively, you can use [this tool](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/tools/openvino-toolkit/download.html) to find the best way in your case.

```
pip install openvino-dev[tensorflow2]
```

**Save your model as SavedModel**

OpenVINO is not able to convert the HDF5 model, so you have to save it as SavedModel first.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from custom_layer import CustomLayer
model = tf.keras.models.load_model('model.h5', custom_objects={'CustomLayer': CustomLayer})
tf.saved_model.save(model, 'model')
```

**Use Model Optimizer to convert SavedModel model**

The Model Optimizer is a command-line tool that comes from OpenVINO Development Package. It converts the Tensorflow model to IR, a default format for OpenVINO. You can also try the precision of FP16, which should give you better performance without a significant accuracy drop (change data_type). Run in the command line:

```
mo --saved_model_dir "model" --data_type FP32 --output_dir "model_ir"
```

**Run the inference**

The converted model can be loaded by the runtime and compiled for a specific device, e.g., CPU or GPU (integrated into your CPU like Intel HD Graphics). I suggest using an AUTO device. It will choose the best hardware for you. Moreover, if you care about latency, provide that performance hint (as shown below). If you depend on throughput, use `THROUGHPUT` or `CUMULATIVE_THROUGHPUT` instead.

```
# Load the network
ie = Core()
model_ir = ie.read_model(model="model_ir/model.xml")
compiled_model_ir = ie.compile_model(model=model_ir, device_name="AUTO", config={"PERFORMANCE_HINT":"LATENCY"})

# Get output layer
output_layer_ir = compiled_model_ir.output(0)

# Run inference on the input image
result = compiled_model_ir([input_image])[output_layer_ir]
```

Disclaimer: I work on OpenVINO.